# a resource allocation optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\vec{\alpha}} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{M}\alpha_i f_i(\alpha_i)\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{M} \alpha_i = \alpha \\
&\alpha_i \geq 0, i = 1,2,\ldots,M    \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $f_i(\alpha_i)$ is a decreasing function with respect to $\alpha_i$ , all $f_i(\alpha_i)$ belong to the same class function, e.g., the exponential function. And they may have different hyperparameters. $M$ is interger, $\alpha$ is a predefined value.

My question is: $f_i(\alpha_i)$ satisfy what conditions, that this problem has optimal solution,and what is the optimal solution?

Thank you for your help!